# Css scrollable inside a container

Tags: html, css

Creating a sample  application.Where i needed to  have a scrollbar when the child-div's are more  .The horizontal scroll bar is not appearing, instead  the child-div's are coming down rather than coming in one horizontal line. could anyone provide any solution for this using css without using jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<style>
.main-div
{
border:2px solid black;
height:300px;
width:300px;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child-div
{
  width:90px;
  border:1px solid black;
  float:left;
}

</style>
</head>
<body style="height:1000px;">

<div class="main-div" >

<div class="child-div" >Header1</div>
<div class="child-div" >Header2</div>
<div class="child-div" >Header3</div>
<div class="child-div" >Header4</div>

 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is for vertical scroll

Place this under your body tag

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="main-div" >

    <div class="child-div" >Header1</div>
    <div class="child-div" >Header2</div>
    <div class="child-div" >Header3</div>
    <div class="child-div" >Header4</div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

And this under style tag

```
main-div
{
  max-height:200px;
  width:100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.child-div
{
  width:100%;
  border:1px solid black;
  height:70px;
  position: relative;
}
```

working fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/nm7s4ahw/3/

Comment: I need for horizontal scroll only I tried placing span but those things are coming one by one down not appearing horizontally